# Spark and Hadoop Testing the Methods

Tags: scala, testing, mockito, hdfs, scalatest

**I have a method which reads files from Hdfs and trying to test this method**

I first tried the HDFSMini cluster without any success. Can this type of methods are testable. If so what dependency are required to test it and how to mock the Hdfs File system locally without installing hadoop. There should be no dependency of hadoop installation. I cannot ask everyone who thinks to test to install hadoop.

```
def readFiles(fs: FileSystem,path: Path): String = {
    val sb = new mutable.StringBuilder()
    var br : BufferedReader =null
    var line : String = ""
    try{
      if(fs.exists(path)){
        if(fs.isFile(path)){
          br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(path)))
          while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            sb.append(line.trim)
        } else {
          throw new InvalidPathException(s"${path.toString} is a directory, please provide the full path")
        }
      }else {
        throw new InvalidPathException(s"${path.toString} is an invalid file path ")
      }
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => throw e
    } finally {
      if (br != null){
        try {
          br.close()
        } catch {
          case e: Exception => throw e
        }
      }
    }

    sb.toString

  }
```

Comment: _how to mock the Hdfs File system_ - Smart people say that _Don't Mock What You Don't Own_. You might agree or not, buy certainly something to consider. And just glancing over your code - what exactly are you trying to test?

Comment: @user6910411 I will read the data from the file and compare asserts it with string .

Comment: @user6910411  If i am able to mock the hdfs, i can read data using dataframe reader and verify it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with *org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem* (same goes for Spark) I usually store test data files in:

> src/test/resources

For instance

> src/test/resources/test.txt

Which is accessible by the local org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem using the path relative to the root of your project, i.e. "src/test/resources/test.txt":

```
test("Some test") {
  val fileSystem = FileSystem.get(new Configuration())
  val fileToRead = new Path("src/test/resources/test.txt")
  val computedContent = readFiles(fileSystem, fileToRead)
  val expectedContent = "todo"
  assert(computedContent === expectedContent)
}
```

Comment: I am getting the following error. Invalid path name ../resources/test.txt is an invalid file path 
org.apache.hadoop.fs.InvalidPathException: Invalid path name ../resources/test.txt is an invalid file path

Comment: Did you use the relative path "../resources/test.txt" relative to your test file? Can you try with the relative path to the root of your project (absolute path within your project structure)? i.e. "src/test/resources/test.txt".

Comment: I added it as relative path and this is the error  ../resources/test.txt

Invalid path name ../resources/test.txt is an invalid file path 
org.apache.hadoop.fs.InvalidPathException: Invalid path name ../resources/test.txt is an invalid file path 
 at com.rxcorp.ds.utils.CommonUtils$.readFiles(CommonUtils.scala:124)

Comment: I meant can you try with "src/test/resources/test.txt" instead of "../resources/test.txt"? where the src is within the root folder of your scala project

Comment: I have run with obsolute path C:/Users/XXX/Documents/Projects/XXX/XXXX/src/test/resources/test.txt  
But now i am getting the  java.lang.NullPointerException was thrown.
java.lang.NullPointerException